# Flutter pubspec.yaml errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

So i discovered that i get some errors from the pubspec.yaml actually 740 or something like that, i don't know what i did wrong. it seems that everything inside is wrong event though i haven't added anything.
I tried removing some code but it makes no difference. I think i added something in the code that's wrong. What could be wrong with this?

Here is a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/376d866b1b4e334df0481a79d45231cf

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show your code. Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: i solved it, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

It would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see there's nothing really wrong with your code all you need to do is try `flutter clean && flutter pub get` or `killall -9 dart` (if you're on macOS) or a combination both.  You might also want to run `flutter upgrade` to make sure you're on the latest version. Lastly, think you should share the full code so others can copy and look at it in case there are other issues.